# How to send data from an MCU over a proxy network

Tags: networking, proxy, dd-wrt, microcontroller

My ultimate goal is to be able to send data from my various microcontrollers over a network that has a proxy firewall. I tried changing the firmware of the different MCUs to support proxy but that came out to be a big daunting task with no guarantee of success and the scalability issue. The feasible answer I found is to use a machine in between the network and these nodes that tunnels the data through the proxy for them.
Now, the obvious answer was to get a cheap pc and make it do it but that was not practical for my applications. The other interesting thing that I found is that there are router firmware such as DD-WRT that support this feature on the routers itself. I was very intrigued and am looking for a definitive answer to this approach for my application.
Is it really possible to make the proxy settings in a router through the DD-WRT firmware and it will tunnel the data of all the devices connected to it through the proxy?
If not, what am I missing here and if there is a better way to go for this problem.
Also, taking as this DD-WRT is linux based, will it be possible to flash it to a raspberry and make it do everything instead?

Thank You

Comment: It's called a "transparent proxy". You might have luck on Google with that.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing something but I don't see how the transparent proxy fits in here. a) I cannot control the proxy network that is already set up by someone else on the field. b) I just want a solution to tunnel the data from my MCU nodes through the proxy network without using a PC

Comment: Anyone? Is it possible to setup DD-WRT to handle the proxy network and broadcast a wireless network through which I can connect my devices with out the proxy settings?

Comment: Yes, although it will probably be easier to do with openwrt instead of dd-wrt. It's called the privoxy package. You can accomplish the same thing with a pptp VPN on dd-wrt. I believe you can now download the same packages from openwrt to ddwrt. Although admittedly I haven't tried swapping packages from one to the other. Not sure about the r-pi, I use esp32's & Arduino nanos.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Have you ever tried to connect your ESP32 to a wireless network with a proxy?